# Merge [fn] into [fn-key]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[fn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fn) tagged questions should probably be merged into the [fn-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fn-key) tag, since **all** of the [fn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fn) tagged questions relate to the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. There are also [questions tagged with both](https://superuser.com/questions/503963/windows-8-fn-key-doesnt-work-for-brightness) [fn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fn) and [fn-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fn-key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. Synonymized and merged.

Thanks for bringing it to our attention.